# Get element with max value from an object in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs

Couldn't find anything about this.

I have this controller:

```
app.controller('StatsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('stats.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.stats = data;
 });
});
```

The stats.json has:

```
{"lang":{"en":28,"und":1,"ja":9,"es":14,"ru":1,"in":1,"ko":1,"th":1,"ar":1}}
```

What I need is to assign the maximum value from the `lang` object to `$scope.max` in the controller. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to assign value(number) to max or key(like "en", "und") to max ?

Comment: @user2393267 the value(number) which would be 28 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a couple of native methods:

```
$scope.max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data.lang).map(function(key) {
    return data.lang[key];
}));
```

Comment: Added this to the controller, but I think I'm missing something, because it doesn't work: `app.controller('StatsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('stats.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.stats = data;
 });
    $scope.max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data.lang).map(function(key) {
    return data.lang[key];
    }));
});`

Comment: Oops, it's working now. Thanks. `app.controller('StatsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('stats.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.stats = data;
    $scope.max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data.lang).map(function(key) {
    return data.lang[key];
    }));
 });
});`

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/kaiser07/6h317Lvv/

```
  var jsonText = '{"lang":{"en":28,"und":1,"ja":9,"es":14,"ru":1,"in":1,"ko":1,"th":1,"ar":1}}';
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonText).lang
    var maxProp = null
    var maxValue = -1
    for (var prop in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var value = data[prop]
        if (value > maxValue) {
          maxProp = prop
          maxValue = value
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use underscore.js `_.max`:

```
_.max(list, [iteratee], [context])
```

Returns the maximum value in list. If an iteratee function is provided, it will be used on each value to generate the criterion by which the value is ranked. -Infinity is returned if list is empty, so an isEmpty guard may be required.

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.max(stooges, function(stooge){ return stooge.age; });
=> {name: 'curly', age: 60};
```

[link](http://underscorejs.org/#max)